# MATE system settings

Tags: mate

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and using MATE.

I am unable to find the tool for settings system preferences.

Anybody know what to do about this?

Comment: "unable to find" means? don't you know where the settings or the settings are missing?...

Comment: btw nevermind just suggestion--don't forget to accept answer which solved your problem.I see your Qs,you not accepted even one :(

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer. I cannot find how to set the colour of the document window, and sound preferences beyond the basic default sounds.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer in Progress**..

keep mouse pointer at top left,

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This answer has been in progress for over two years?

Answer (score 0):

it is the "main menu" one in system -> preferences (or just in preferences if you use the other layouts)